# How to use the flag [P] in RewriteRule Apache configuration?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to create RewriteRule on my Apache Server.

The rule works correctly but when I add the flag [P] It doesn't work any more

Here is what I'm tring to achieve

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =coucou.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/apex/f?p=example:mypage [L,P]
```

Am I missing something please ?

Cheers, Regards,

Comment: Do you have `mod_proxy` enabled? (Aside: Using `P` implies `L`, so you don't also need `L`.)

Comment: What is the problem you are having?